# Can I export azure devops pipelines run history using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

So what I want to know is if its possible to generate a report that will tell us all the pipelines that have been run in the past month, how long they took, any failures.

If so, how can I do it?

Here is some script iv got so far

```
$strURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{chealey}/{personal test}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1"
$filePath="D:\"
$fileName=$filePath+"\pipeline.json"
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $strURL -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method GET -OutFile $fileName
```

Comment: Did you start by looking at the REST API documentation for Azure DevOps?

Comment: Iv been taking a look. Im pretty new so its a bit annoying to understand.

Comment: Documentation and Google are excellent starting points. If you have a specific issue with implementation that you'd like help with, feel free to ask a *specific* question here.

Comment: Thank you :).  

Well one thing im not so sure about is where I put my script. Do I clone it to Azure devops, run it in powershell/VS code? 

Iv found a script which iv added to the question description. Iv added the organization/project name but im getting errors. One being 'Resource cannot be found' and 'the variable  'pipeline' is assigned but never used.

Comment: It depends on how you intend to use the script. For development purposes, running it locally is fine. Don't just copy and paste code from other sources without understanding what it is you're using. The script you put in your question is clearly designed to be run as part of an Azure Pipeline, because of the presence of the `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` variable.

Answer (score -1):

You can RUNS Rest Api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

As example:

```
$user = ""
$token = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$orgUrl = $env:SYSTEM_COLLECTIONURI
$teamProject = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT


$restApiGetBuildDefinitions = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=6.1-preview.7"
$restApiGetBuildRunsTemplate = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/pipelines/{BUILD_DEF_ID}/runs?api-version=6.1-preview.1"


function InvokeGetRequest ($GetUrl)
{    
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}    
}


$buildDefs = InvokeGetRequest $restApiGetBuildDefinitions

foreach ($buildDef in $buildDefs.value)
{
    $restApiGetBuildRuns = $restApiGetBuildRunsTemplate -replace "{BUILD_DEF_ID}", $buildDef.id

    $buildRuns = InvokeGetRequest $restApiGetBuildRuns

    if ($buildRuns.count -gt 0)
    {
        Write-Host "Build Definition:" $buildDef.name
        Write-Host "| Run Id | Start Date | Finish Date | Result |"
        Write-Host "|--------|------------|-------------|--------|"

        foreach ($buildRun in $buildRuns.value)
        {
            Write-Host "|" $buildRun.id "|" $buildRun.createdDate "|" $buildRun.finishedDate "|" $buildRun.result "|"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it simply provides the person with code. We should be helping people *learn* to code, not writing code for them.